# JavaFX - bidirectional binding either doesn't work or stops working

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding

I'm working on a Sudoku game project. I have javafx buttons representing 81 boxes, stored in boardButtons list and userBoard which is an object of my other class (doesn't matter now I think). Method getField() returns object field which stores value of this sudoku field. I want to use bidirectional binding (it needs to be like that), so that when I select a box to and input some value, it not only shows in this box, but is also saved in userBoard's Field and vice versa.
When I run the app, after entering some values to the boxes, they stop being saved to userBoard's field. Sometimes it happens right at the beginning and sometimes I manage to enter a few numbers. I've searched for solution online but I have no idea why that happens.

```
StringConverter converter = new IntegerStringConverter();

    boardButtons.forEach((button) -> {
        try {
            index = boardButtons.indexOf(button);
            IntegerProperty fieldValueProperty = new JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder()
                    .bean(userBoard.getField(index))
                    .name("fieldValue").build();

            button.textProperty().bindBidirectional(fieldValueProperty, converter);

            fieldValueProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
                    if (gameStarted) {
                        System.out.println("fieldValueProperty changed: " + fieldValueProperty);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not use directional binding? The button's text should never change so (except for code you didn't post) you should be able to use .bind() instead.

Comment: @TagHoward I didn't provide all the information - it needs to be bidirectional as there is also a need to modify buttons text not from the direct input, but from the stored userBoard - for example to reset sudoku and do some other things. So I want to stick to bidirectional binding

Comment: It will be very difficult if you put all of them into arrays. I think this will help you https://github.com/jcollard/captaincoder/tree/master/Java/sudoku-javafx

Comment: Please post [mre] of the problem

Comment: Java bean properties only trigger changes, if you do any modifications through the property object. Any direct access to the beans methods cannot be observed, so you've basically created a binding that effectively works only in one direction anyways; Changes done to the `fieldValue` property directly won't trigger any updates of the property objects. To change this you need to make the `fieldValue` property observable somehow which would be easiest to do using a `SimpleIntegerProperty`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there's not really enough information to offer a proper solution, I can explain why your bidirectional binding will eventually stop working.

**TL;DR:** Your `fieldValueProperty` is being garbage collected.

The core libraries of JavaFX attempt to prevent memory leaks as much as possible. This typically involves the use of weak references in the implementation of listeners/bindings. Also, the current implementation of bidirectional bindings is done via a third, behind-the-scenes class to which you have no access. This behind-the-scenes class only maintains weak references to *both properties* involved in the binding. This prevents one property from holding the other in memory, which is important because you can't undo a bidirectional binding if you only have a reference to one of the properties (unlike unidirectional bindings).

Basically, this is a long-winded way to say that you are not maintaining a strong reference to `fieldValueProperty` and thus it is likely to be garbage collected at some point. You may think that:

```java
fieldValueProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
        if (gameStarted) {
            System.out.println("fieldValueProperty changed: " + fieldValueProperty);
        }
    }
});
```

Has a strong reference to `fieldValueProperty` via the listener, but notice that you're adding the listener to `fieldValueProperty` itself. In other words, it's a self-reference which does not prevent garbage collection. An obvious, though probably naive, solution is to simply add a strong reference to `fieldValueProperty`. But consider having your model class expose a JavaFX property—rather than using a JavaBean adapter—and binding to that property instead; as long as the model class is in memory so will be the property, and I believe that would be the more elegant solution.

---

Note that unidirectional bindings don't suffer the same problems. When you bind a `Property` to an `ObservableValue` the former maintains a strong reference to the latter, but not vice versa. This is okay because you can invoke `unbind()` to remove the reference yourself.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot